# Reading Linux kernel parameters

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Is there a way to find the parameters passes to the kernel (/proc/cmdline) at boot time without reading any files in proc? I might have a process that needs to read the boot parameters before /proc is mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the kernel passes anything on the boot line as a arg to init- unless there is a ' = ' or a ' . '

[Passing Linux boot opts to Init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944692/passing-linux-boot-opts-to-init)

Comment: And I believe init sets those into an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way, but I do see it in dmesg

Comment: humm...  I don't think that will work either.  I'm hoping there is a a function in the C lib that will come up with the info. Maybe I should add the C tag to the question.  The process that needs this info will be run as init (it will be the first process) and needs to digest the info before exec() the real init process.

Comment: @tMC: First thought.  Make your program mount `/proc`. :-)

Comment: @mikel - it might have too.  But I was hoping to group the start up processes differently.  I was just hoping there was a function in the libs I could exec via ctypes or an interface I could fnclt before starting my bootup process.

Comment: @robin - yes, most of it is already written, i just hate the the shebang is hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to understand your requirements better, because you are pretty much guaranteed to have `/proc` mounted.  Mounting `/proc` is one of the very first things that `init` does.

Ubuntu with upstart: `/etc/init/mountall.conf`, part of the `startup` event
Fedora with initscripts: `/etc/rc.sysinit`, second thing it does (after setting the hostname)

Your code is almost certain to run after this.

---

Seeing as you're replacing `init`, take a look at how `init` does it. [init git repo](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=init/main.c;h=4a9479ef4540df99586d5e0b3854c2b3c46d91c4;hb=HEAD).

There seems to be a global symbol called `boot_command_line`.

Comment: I'm rewriting init in an interrupted language (python).  I'd like to pass the path to the python interrupter as a boot option, but since init will be a python script, I need to know where the path to the interrupter is before I can exec() my init process.

Comment: LOL, Python as an *interrupted* language - that made my day :)